# Generating a new random number for a random number guessing game using a do-while loop

Tags: java

Objective: Create a game that randomly generates a number from 1-100 and asks the user to guess it.

The issue is: I'm trying to generate a new number after I ask the user if they want to continue if not exit the program and if they do then I want to generate a new random number for them. I'm not sure how to do this.

If someone can help me that would be great,
Thank you!

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class SuperRandom
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randy = new Random();

        //#declaring variables
        int num, count = 0;
        final int random = randy.nextInt(100);
        final int randoms = randy.nextInt(100);
        String input;
        char yn;

        //#random number
        System.out.println("Num = " + random);

        //#title or header
        System.out.println("Random Number Guessing Game");
        System.out.println("===========================");

        //#asking user for input
        do
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Guess the random number " + 
                    "from 1 to 100===> ");
                num = keyboard.nextInt();

                //#if the number the user entered
                //#was less than the random number
                if(num < random)
                {
                    //#display this message
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low try again...");
                    System.out.println();
                    if (num < 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input" +
                            "\nYour guess cannot be a negative" +
                            " number");
                    }
                }
                //#if the number the user entered
                //#was less than the random number
                if(num > random)
                {
                    //#display this message
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high try again...");
                    System.out.println();
                    if (num > 100)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input"+
                           "\nYour guess cannot be above 100");
                    }

                }

                count++;
                if (num == random) 
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed the random number in " + 
                        count + " guesses!");
                    break;
                } 

            }
            while (num > 1 || num < 100);
            yn = 'x'; 
            System.out.print("Continue? (Y or N)==> ");
            input = keyboard.next();
            yn = input.charAt(0);

        }
        while (yn == 'Y' || yn == 'y');

    }
}
```

Comment: Move `final int random = randy.nextInt(100);` into the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the random number at the beginning or at the end of the outer loop. In that case you would need to remove the final keyword from random's declaration, since that tells the compiler that the value should never change.

```java
// declarations and header
int random;
//#asking user for input
        do
        {
            random = randy.nextInt(100); // here
            System.out.println("Num = " + random);
          do
            {
              // guessing loop
            }
            while (num > 1 || num < 100);
            random = randy.nextInt(100); // or here if you want to keep the line that generates the random number before the loop


            // checks for continue
         }
         while (yn == 'Y' || yn == 'y');
```

Obviously generating it at the beginning of the outer loop is probably best.

Also I don't know what you meant with the inner loop  guard, but any integer satisfies greater than 1 or less than 100.